# How can I hide non-sensitive credentials on a Google Colab Notebook?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a Google Colab Notebook that is using `psycopg2` to connect with a free Heroku PostgreSQL instance. I'd like to share the notebook with some colleagues for educational purposes to view and run the code.

There is nothing sensitive related to the account / database but would still like to hide the credentials used to make the initial connection without restricting their access.

Answer (score 1):

My work around was creating a Python module that contained a function who performed the initial connection with credentials. I converted the module into a binary `.pyc`, uploaded it to Google Drive, downloaded the binary into the Notebook's contents via shell command then used it as an import.

It obviously isn't secure but provides the obfuscation layer I was looking for.